# Why and who: named some fish "bashers" (African electrofish taxon "stonebasher")

Tags: taxonomy, literature, ichthyology, etymology

Folklore question for itinerant elephantfish/electrofish experts happening to see this:Is any stonebasher fish named for a behavior related to bashing...
something or some part of its anatomy against some stone, somewhere? Nonbiologist (so far) or certainly not grad level, so I don't know what mailing list archives or other sites are out there here in English-Interwebs-land.

20 minutes of wikipedia, goog, bing etc yields nothing, but maybe one of the tree-of-life type phylogenome-DB sites has a "history, indigenous and non-scientific names, etc." field? I found none on the sites I looked at (2-3 sites) via footnotes on eng.wikipedia.com references.

Probable possible source might be a print publication from around the period of first characterization of whichever one was named first.

Best imaginable answer would be who saw what on what day when, with an excerpt from field notes, but any reference helps!

Thanks for the welcome! I'm off to read the new member's tour

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please visit the [help] and take a [tour] for more information about the site. In particular one of the requirements here is that askers make some attempt to answer a question for themselves. Having said that; common names often don't have a source, unlike scientific names which do have an origin/attribution associated with them. Stonebashers seem to be a informal group from a few genera within one family. None of the scientific names have to do with stone.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Sorry, and thanks. Just falling in love with this "place" via the Mathematics exchanges, and dived in to add sites without taking individual stacks' tours. Now I know to do that first. (unfortunately un-)common courtesy for the win!

Comment: l should have mentioned several general Google searches, which I will now repeat with bing, and any bio/zoölogy or hopefully ichth specific search engines or preprint-server searchlinks those of you who happen to see this may chance to recommend.  I know this is only likely to be easy in places where people who know "folklore" of taxonomic adventurers past, tho'!